# A couple questions regarding anagrams

Tags: java, list, anagram

This is a follow on to a couple questions I've already asked. Earlier I asked how to use a method to determine if elements of one list were present in another. The reason I did this is because I would like like to determine if one list contains anagrams of the other - using user input and a dictionary list. I'm having trouble determining this. I want to pass the lists into a method to determine if one contains the elements of another. Right now it only returns false when I know there is a real anagram present.

Could someone look at my code and help me figure it out? Also, how would I modify this to determine if user input contained multi-word anagrams?

My algorithm works by taking in the two lists and alphabetizing the letters in each word. I'd read about this method in another post and decided to go with it - it remains a work in progress. Here is my code:

```
public class AnagramSolver1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Scanner/Reader
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/dictionary.txt"));

    //Lists to contain unsorted dictionary and input and after alphabetical sort
    List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<char[]> dictionarySort = new ArrayList<char[]>();
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<char[]> inputSort = new ArrayList<char[]>();

    String line = null;

    //read in dictionary then sort alphabetically////
    while (null!=(line=in.readLine()))
    {
       dictionary.add(line);
    }
    in.close();

    dictionarySort = sortList(dictionary);

    //print statement
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < dictionarySort.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(dictionarySort.get(i));
    }*/

    //User input, scan in then sort alphabetically////
    System.out.println("Enter Word: ");

    String input = scan.next();

    inputList.add(input);

    inputSort = sortList(inputList);

    //print statement
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < inputSort.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(inputSort.get(i));
    }*/

    //determine if user input is an angram of any dictionary word
    boolean isAnagram = isAnagram(dictionarySort, inputSort); 
    System.out.println(isAnagram);

}

//sort a string into a char array
public static List<char[]> sortList (List<String>sort){

    List<char[]> sortList = new ArrayList<char[]>();
    char[] letterSort;

      for (int i = 0; i < sort.size(); i++) {
          letterSort = sort.get(i).toCharArray();
          Arrays.sort(letterSort);
          sortList.add(letterSort);
      }

    return sortList;    
}
//Determines if User input is an Anagram or not.
public static boolean isAnagram (List<char[]>dictionarySort, List<char[]>inputSort){

    for (char[] c : dictionarySort) {
            if (inputSort.contains(c)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a major bug here:

```
for (char[] c : dictionarySort) {
    if (inputSort.contains(c)) { // BUG!
```

This won't work like you think it will. This tests if the *exact same `char[]` object* is contained in the list; it does *not* test if a char array that has the same characters is there.

To work the way you intend, don't store `char[]`, store `Strings`.

To turn a `char[]` into a `String`, do this:

```
char[] c;
String s = new String(s);
```

Once you have sorted your chars in an array, turn the char array into a String and store that in your lists. It means that all Lists should be lists of `List<String>`.

Comment: Ok. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks so how would convert a list<char[]> into a list<string>? It looks you kind of explained but could give me a little more detail?

Comment: Hold on. I think I just answered my own question. I already converted from a String to a Char...I guess just go in reverse right?

Comment: well you converted to `char[]` so you could sort the chars, which is fine, now convert back as per my snippet and add the new String to your "sorted" list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine if one word is an anagram of another, sort the letters of both words and the resulting strings must be equal if the words are anagrams.

Try this:

- When loading your dictionary, sort the letters of each word.  Store the sorted value as well as the dictionary value.  Consider storing the dictionary words in a hash map that uses the sorted value as the key and has multiple words as the value.
- Sort the letters of the user input.
- Search the dictionary (possibly the map) using the sorted user input.
- When displaying anagrams from your dictionary, be sure to remove the user input from the list of anagrams (blam is not an anagram of blam).

There are two ways (that I know) to put multiple values in a HashMap.

1. Store a List as the value and add to it as you read the dictionary.
2. Use a MultiMap (google has some available; I think the project is guava).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried sorting into Hashmaps previously. The problem I encountered was that many sorted words would be duplicates and a Hashmap can't have duplicate keys. The point of me alphabetizing is to produce duplicates which is how I would ID an anagram. Do you have any advice on how to overcome this obstacle?.

Comment: @dave Make a HashMap whilest having the key be the original word and the value be the sorted word. For example: K: Raccoon, V: accnoor

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the contains from the list interface implements equals(), in the case of arrays what is being compared is the memory address of the two char[]'s. What you need to do is:

**Option 1)** Get your program to compare with the elements in dictionary against input using Arrays.equals(char[] one, char[] two), that will compare the contents.

**Option 2)** Instead of comparing the char[] get it to a point where you are comparing strings, using the string's equals() method which will also compare the contents.